# How to set Cmder to not wrap text output

Tags: windows, settings, cmder

The default setting for Cmder is to wrap text output. But how to set Cmder do not wrap text output?

The Cmder, i meant : http://cmder.net/

Comment: did you figure it out ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of now, I don't believe there is a way to disable text wrapping.

Someone did open an issue related to [disabling line wrapping](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/166).
However, as featured in [ConEmu's Roadmap](http://conemu.github.io/en/RoadMap.html#horizontal-scrolling):

> Current ConEmu version allows neither horizontal scrolling nor setting horizontal buffer size.

Comment: did anyone figure this out?

Comment: @SachinSharma Write it to an output file?

Comment: @Jon49 Yup. Simple and easy. :-)

Comment: fatal flaw in both conemu and cmder

Comment: Agree this is really needed.

Comment: On windows cmd: I simply set line buffer 2x of window size, so it doesn't wraps, not sure how to do it cmder

Answer (score 5):

Try running command ***`mode`***, then you will see parameters below.

### Status for device CON:

```
Lines:          xxxx
Columns:        xxxx
Keyboard rate:  xx
Keyboard delay: x
Code page:      xxx
```

Remember the value of **Columns**, just in case you want to roll it back. Now execute command **`mode 1000`** and the **Column** parameter should change to **1000**.  (or use any higher number till you get desired result)

*This also works on cmd and powershell.*