# How to configure cmdr no line wrap?

Tags: conemu

I do not want "cmdr" to wrap lines , even if visible window size is smaller than line size.

How do configure that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set Cmder to not wrap text output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214981/how-to-set-cmder-to-not-wrap-text-output)