# how to disable long-line wrapping in conemu console?

Tags: conemu

how to disable long-line wrapping in console?
I can't find any setting where I can specify to not wrap long lines at the right edge.
I'm ok with having horizontal scrollbar for long lines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set Cmder to not wrap text output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214981/how-to-set-cmder-to-not-wrap-text-output)

Answer (score 3):

I believe at the current moment there is no support for horizontal scrolling. Some applications like wmic.exe are able to set large buffers which may be useful instead of wrapping but there is no horizontal scrolling in ConEmu in the current version.

See website, section 'Horizontal scrolling': https://conemu.github.io/en/RoadMap.html